# Joomla managed hosting?

Tags: joomla, hosting

Is there any good Joomla managed hosting? There are many for wordpress, what about Joomla? I just know Joomlapipe but is that the only provider?

Can anyone suggest any other provider?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to visit [binaryhound](http://binaryhound.com) IT is 
is a recently released Managed Hosting service provider for (Joomla/wordpress & Drupal). 
You may Visit the website
http://binaryhound.com/ for more details. Hope this helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

[Rochen](http://rochen.com) - they also host [Joomla.org](http://joomla.org), their [Joomla! offerings page is here](http://www.rochenhost.com/joomla-hosting). We've been using them for a just over a year and while we use the MDS and MVS products they literally manage every aspect which can be difficult to get used if you've been doing it all yourself.

Comment: are they Managed Joomla Hosting? they look after the Joomla like daily monitoring, screening the third party plugins, etc..

Comment: I don't know about third party plugins but for us they do Joomla!, PHP, MySQL etc updates automatically. As their pages say they have custom Joomla! plugins that integrate with their systems and they monitor and backup automatically as well.